# Automatically change dropdown value when source value changed

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I've seen a few things related to this, but haven't come across anything that worked.  I have an Excel workbook with two worksheets, named "Roster" and "July".  On the Roster worksheet, in cells E8:E507, I have a range of values named "Students".  On the July worksheet, in cell C12, I have a dropdown list created through data validation and naming the Students range as the source.  All of this works fine.

My problem is that if I select a value in the dropdown menu, and then change the source value in the Roster worksheet, it doesn't automatically reflect that change back on the July worksheet.

Is there a macro that would make any dropdowns refresh automatically when their source ranges are changed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it when you add to the list of Students that it doesn't update when you add to it?

I've just checked and my list validations are OK when I change it.  Does pressing F9 (calculate) help at all?

If it's a problem with adding to the list then you'll need dynamic named ranges, which aren't too difficult when you come to set up for the first time, but can be a bit time consuming if you need more than one or two.

Maudise

Comment: Maudise: No, that's not the problem.  It's if I select an entry from the dropdown, and then go back and change that same entry in the source list.  I'd like the value in the dropdown to automatically refresh.

Comment: Oh, in which case I'm not sure how you'd do it without some relatively complex VBA code, which depending on how many cells it would affect would dictate the worth of doing it.  The other way, would be to create a table of options, and the cell used as the drop down, is not the cell to be viewed, so having something which offsets to the final option.  A clearer way of explaining is that the user selects an option in cell B2 but it is actually C2 which displays the answer you'd like to use